# How do I find out if my Open Graph app has already been added to the Timeline programmatically?

Tags: javascript, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-timeline

Assume, that besides using the "Add to Timeline" Social Plugin I want to show a specific message to the user only if she did not yet add my app to her Timeline.

Is there any method in the JavaScript SDK that lets me check for that?

Answer (score 1):

According to what i have read, add to Timeline plugin is available through the Javascript SDK via the  XFBML tag.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/

There doesn't seem to be a call that we can subscribe to at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no coverage of how to read from the timeline via the various APIs [yet].

However you can capture and save the ID of any post made, store that in your local database and use it to reference off of either for determining what to share or to let them delete previous posts.

This is a good practice even if the ID doesn't help you as both Facebook and the user want you to be transparent in your posting and the management of said posts.